# How to find sine of the third angle of a triangle, given sines of two other angles and the length of a side between these angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Basically, we have an ASA triangle. But if we are given the sines of the angles instead of the angles themselves, we have that weird case that the sine is positive for all angles from $0$ to $\pi$, thus I cannot really judge whether the triangle is obtuse or acute, so arcsin won't do well to find the third angle as usual.

Though, as we're looking for the sine of that angle, it should be well-determined due to the aforementioned fact that the sine is positive in $(0;\pi)$.

Using sine theorem leads to the system of equations that are not helping because no matter which two expressions of the sine theorem you equate, they narrow down to the third expression, giving no useful information.

What is the formula or thought procedure to find that sine?

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, a positive value of $\sin\theta$ corresponds to two distinct values of $\theta$, one acute and one obtuse. (Forget the trivial case that $\sin\theta=1$ by now.)

Therefore, when you are given the values of $\sin A$ and $\sin B$, there are 4 cases (in fact 3):

Case 1 (always possible) : $A$ and $B$ are both acute.

Case 2 (may be possible) : $A$ is acute and $B$ is obtuse.

Case 3 (may be possible) : $A$ is obtuse and $B$ is acute.

Case 4 (impossible) : $A$ and $B$ are both obtuse.

It is natural that you cannot determine a unique value of the third angle.

###### Edited

When the third angle (noted as $C$) is unique, $A$ and $B$ are both acute (Case 1). In this case, we have $\cos A=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2 A}$ and $\cos B=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2 B}$. Then $\sin C$ can be found by using the compound angle formula of sine.

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin C & =\sin(\pi-A-B) \\
& =\sin(A+B) \\
& =\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A \\
& =\sin A\sqrt{1-\sin^2 B}+\sin B\sqrt{1-\sin^2 A}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Please note: I am also given the length of a side between these angles.

Comment: @Rusurano the third side is not of any help

Comment: @DS Still, there must exist cases where the sine will be absolutely clear. For example, when taking an obtuse angle will violate the sum of the angles of a triangle rule. Take sin(60 degrees) and sin(75 degrees) as an example. Taking an obtuse angle with the same sine will instantly violate the rule. Thus we are left with the only possible case. In that family of cases, how to calculate the sine of the third angle which of course exists and is unique due to the aforementioned circumstances?

Comment: @Rusurano I have edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @Yuta in other words, if I have the cosines of two angles instead of sines, and a side, I'm going to have a well-defined triangle?